# how to use the user time picked from fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-activity

I have created a time picker fragment and date picker fragment just as it suggests from http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/controls/pickers.html .
 Now since the user can pick the time and date, i want to use that time, but my code is in the activity class. Is there any way I can make a variable of the time and date picked and send it to the activity?

Comment: You can use interface as a callback to the activity. You can use EventBus by green robots.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes there is a proper way:

```
public static class FinishTimePickerFragment extends DialogFragment
        implements TimePickerDialog.OnTimeSetListener {

    @Override
    public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Use the current time as the default values for the picker

        int hour = 22;
        int minute = 0;

        // Create a new instance of TimePickerDialog and return it
        return new TimePickerDialog(getActivity(), this, hour, minute,
                DateFormat.is24HourFormat(getActivity()));
    }

    public void onTimeSet(TimePicker view, int hourOfDay, int minute) {
        // Do something with the time chosen by the user
        YourActivity activity = (YourActivity) getActivity();
        activity.a_function_declared_in_your_activity(hourOfDay, minute);
    }
}
```

You must get an instance of your activity in onTimeSet () and then call whatever method you want with the user selected time/date as its arguments.

Comment: Thank you so much. I am fairly new android developer, and I am still learning. If you have any tips or comments, please share. It might help me in the future and others who this page.